# How to Resolve Typescript Error Unexpected Token Import?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm writing an Angular 4 theme for Wordpress 4.8 to be used on mainly Edge and Chrome browsers.  My test script fails on test.ts with the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import at src/test.js:1
```

My tsconfig.json in the \src folder is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "module": "commonjs",
  "target": "es5",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "lib": [ "es2016", "es5", "dom"],
  "noImplicitAny": true,
  "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
}
}
```

tsconfig.json at the root level is:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
  "baseUrl": "src",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "declaration": false,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "target": "es5",
  "typeRoots": [
     "node_modules/@types"
     ],
  "lib": [
     "es2016",
     "dom",
     "es5"
     ]
  }
 }
```

My test.ts consists of:

```
import {BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting} from 
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing";
import {getTestBed} from "@angular/core/testing";

declare var _karma_: any;
declare var require: any;

_karma_.loaded = function () {};

getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);

const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);

context.keys().map(context);

_karma_.start();
```

What would be the best approach to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will see the same issue if you cd to your ./app/ui directory  and run `tsc -p .` there...

the problem is that your are using **"module": "system"** in your **tsconfig.json**

TypeScript has two strategies to resolve module names:

- node - mimics the way how module names are resolved in NodeJS classic
- original strategy that doesn't take node_modules into account when walking up the folder structure looking for modules (see
  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html
  for details). Strategy can be specified via moduleResolution compiler
  option. If this option is omitted compiler will use node when target
  module kind is commonjs and classic otherwise So, in your case
  classic resolution is used, and modules from node_modules are not
  found. I'd suggest specifying resolution explicitly in your config:

  **"moduleResolution": "node",**

does it help?

Comment: Should this be added to the top level tsconfig.json or the one inside the src folder?

Comment: @SidC Please follow this link https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205979284-Typescript-does-not-resolve-modules-through-tsconfig-json-s-baseUrl-

Answer (score 3):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import at src/test.js:1

`import` should be compiled away by TypeScript

## Fix

Make sure that `ts` is actually passing through the TypeScript compiler (to get *actual* JS).

This is a configuration error. `"module": "es6",` is wrong. Suggest using `"module": "commonjs",` with webpack.

## More

Quickstart https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html